# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11 out of bounds for length 7

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-tree, subtree

why this error is occuring?

this is my array declaration :
int[] mainTree = {1,2,4,-1,-1,5,-1,-1,3,-1,-1};

This array is being used to make a binary tree, and here -1 indicates a null value, but I cannot figure out why this error is being displayed.

Comment: Without seeing your code and the full stack trace of the exception, it is impossible to say.

Comment: That array is not related to the error. Search for other arrays of length 7.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).